# Trying to use a variable and string to set a Label Caption value

Tags: vba, ms-access, variables

I am trying to use a Interger Variable to set the Label Captions.
This works ...

```
Public Int_Company_Chosen As Interger

Forms!StartUp.Label_Company_12.Caption = "TrueeBB"
```

These do NOT work...

```
 ("Forms!StartUp.Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen - 1 & ".Caption")
Int_Company_Chosen = 12

strTest1 = ("StartUp.Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen - 1)
Forms!StartUp(strTest1).Caption = "TrueeAZ"

Me(strTest1).Caption = "TrueeZZ"

Forms!StartUp.[(strTest1)].Caption = "TrueeZZ"
```

Thank y'all in advance!!

Comment: Good example of how implicit default member calls confuse people. If this code is in the form's code-behind, you can (read: *should*) drop the `Forms!StartUp` part and replace it with `Me`. Then, instead of implicitly invoking the `Controls` collection through implicit default member call voodoo, spell out what you want to do: `Me.Controls(nameOfTheControl).Caption = value`. And that's still too many dots-per-instruction to my taste. Consider declaring the label control and `Set theLabel = Me.Controls(nameOfTheControl)` and then do `theLabel.Caption = value`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the control name in the controls collection of the form:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Int_Company_Chosen As Integer

    Int_Company_Chosen = 2

    Forms!Startup.Controls("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueBB"

End Sub
```

[MSDN Controls Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214293(v=office.12).aspx)

**Edit:**

Another way to work through the controls on the form:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim frm As Form
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim x As Long

    Set frm = Forms!Startup

    For Each ctl In frm.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
            x = x + 1
            ctl.Caption = "Label #" & x
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on that one, but it's possible `Forms!Startup` is referring to the *default instance* of the form; if the displayed form isn't the default instance, that won't work. If that code is in the form's code-behind, seriously consider doing `Me.Controls` instead of fetching the `Controls` collection from some global-scope `Forms` collection.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  ahh, so that's your real name. :)  Yes, was considering adding the alternative `Me` reference for when the code's in the form.  Hadn't considered the OP opening multiple instances of the same form though.... I'd say most users (incl. me) generally use a single instance of a form using commands like `DoCmd.Openform....`  Opening a form as an instance of a class is better.  Not being from an OOP background I still have trouble getting my head around it even though I know the basics and can see the possibilities.

Comment: You're probably doing it right then - I don't do MS-Access... just good to know that if the code assumes it's a single or default instance, then it's going to break whenever it's an actual `New` instance. I'd believe treating forms as class modules leads to better code, since it'll work with `DoCmd.OpenForm` *and* a `New` instance, whereas the opposite isn't true ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Darren! I started way back in the day with Pascal. It gave me the basics. I have worked a little with VBA and have taken it one step at the time. Let me make sure I understand.
    Forms!Startup.Controls("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueBB"
Will work but 
    Me.Controls("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueBB"
Would be better. The Me does get the (Control?)... I will try it!
Thanks again for the help!!
Joe

Comment: I did a little Pascal back in the day, but started on Sinclair & BBC basic - where your only hope of help was from a magazine written by someone who eats astrophysics for breakfast and can't talk in words of less than 100 syllables.   Anyway.... if your code is sitting within the form you can reference the form using the `Me` keyword. [Me Keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/me-keyword)

Comment: `Me.Controls("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueBB"`.  It's the form you're referencing as `Me`.  So `Me.Label_Company_10.Caption = "Testing"` should work.

Comment: I have tried:
This works!
    Me.Label_Company_11.Caption = "Junkky"
    Me.Label_Company_10.Caption = "Testing"

This does not work... Returns the error 24654 with the message could not find the field 'Label_Company_10' refereed to  ...

    Forms!Startup.Controls("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueBB"

    Me.Controls("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueBB"

    Me("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueCC"
        Forms!Startup("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueEE"

hmmm.....

Comment: True this works;
Me.Label_Company_10.Caption = "Testing"   

But this doesn't Work.... 
 Int_Company_Chosen = 10
 Me("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "Testing"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The underscore where the spaces were caused the error!
Should be ...

```
Me.Controls("Label Company " & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueBB"
```

Not...

```
Me.Controls("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption = "TrueBB"
```

Thanks for the Help!! Joe